# Dragable shapes in WPF with childs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop, shapes

I've a problem with my shapes application. I want a app which can make schema's out of XML. 
My problem is the drag option for the parents. So i can have a ellipse with two rectangles in it for example. When I drag the parent, it has to drag the childs as well.

How I set it up:

```
<contentcontrol>
   <itemscontrol>
      <ellipse>Parent</ellipse>
   </itemscontrol>
   <itemscontrol>
      <rectangle>Child1</rectangle>
   </itemscontrol>
   <itemscontrol>
      <rectangle>Child2</rectangle>
   </itemscontrol>
</contentcontrol>
```

I think it's not possible to have more objects at the contentcontrol. My contentcontrol is allowed to drag and drop, and when it's like this, it's also allowed to drag and drop the childs with it

BUT, the problem with this, the positioning doesn't fit when I just draw it on the canvas. So with the itemscontrol my whole idea with the positioning is screwed. What is a good alternative of a solution to this problem?

Can somebody help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Remember, `ContentControl` is itself a `Control`, allowing you to nest them:

Compiled in VS2013 C#

```
<ContentControl>
    <ItemsControl>
        <!-- One shape in the top level parent. -->
        <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Stroke="#FFDE3737" />
        <ContentControl>
            <ItemsControl>
                <!-- Multiple shapes in one sub-parent -->
                <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Stroke="#FFDE3737" />
                <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Stroke="#FFDE3737" />
            </ItemsControl>
        </ContentControl>
    </ItemsControl>
</ContentControl>
```

EDIT: A useful tip to know when working with WPF composition. Many `Controls` derive from the same base `Control`. In that manner, they form a kind of *composite pattern* allowing you to nest them very deeply when necessary.

Comment: Allright, now I've a Contentcontrol which has as content the Itemscontrol. And the "parent" and all the "childs" are added to the itemscontrol. But how can I position the childs within the parent? Before I had all the shapes added to a contentcontrol, but then Everything is drag and droppable. But I want only my parent be drag/drop and then the childs would move with it. So that's why I use 1 contentcontrol (which can drag) and a itemscontrol in it with all the shapes.

Comment: `OnClick` or `OnDragDrop` events bubble from the the most nested components upwards. The method you use for drag dropping the top-level `ContentControl` could be applied to children. In that manner, the child `ContentControl`'s would then have drag drop abilities independent of any parent `ContentControl`'s.

Comment: But with your solution, the 2 ellipsen can't be positioned in the way the canvas is? So it won't help me like that. I want all my shapes positioned on the canvas, the groupes has to be in the contentcontrol within some panel or something. But it won't screw the positioning up.